# Get codebehind to create a complete JS section

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want my codebehind to dump a very large set of JS into the ASPX page. This is required, as I can't use external JS code for this component, and the code is also unique to each customer. Is it possible to do this from codebehind? I know how to set the value of text boxes etc. (.Text/.Value = xxx) but I can't see how I can just 'dump' code straight onto the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set a string variable into code behind and then add to the page just

```
<%= variableName %>
```

where you want your js code to be dumped to

Or if you like you can create a method and do the same thing

```
<%= methodName() %>
```

Answer (score 1):

have a look at Page.ClientScripts.RegisterStartupScriptBlock or RegisterScriptBlock, these method do exactly what you need.

Comment: This should do the trick. I recommend using StringBuilder to build your large javascript string - it is much more efficient that concatenations when doing lots of string appending.

Answer (score 1):

Try using RegisterClientScript:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Register_Client_Script.aspx